# Create a string containg optgroup and option in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a string variable to append on a multiselect with jquery.

This is the fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/47084/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var group = "<optgroup></optgroup>";

  $(group).attr("value", 1);
  $(group).attr("label", "test group");

  var t = "<option></option>";

  $(t).attr("value", 4);
  $(t).text("Test option");
  $(t).attr("selected", true);

  $(group).append(t);


  $("#a").html(group);
});
```

```css
body {
  padding: 5px;
}

label {
  font-weight: bold;
}

input[type=text] {
  width: 20em
}

p {
  margin: 1em 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
RESULT TEST PURPOSE:
<br><br>
EXPECTED:
<br>
<textarea rows="5" cols="72">
<optgroup value="1" label="test group">
  <option value="4" selected>Test option</option>
</optgroup>"
</textarea>
<br><br>
GET:
<br>
<label id="a"></label>
```

Next step is to append the string created dinamically in a select with

```
$("#select").append(group);
```

But the string is not created...it result empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues here. Firstly you're attempting to append an `optgroup` element to a `label`. This is impossible as `optgroup` can only be children of `select` elements.

Secondly, `optgroup` elements do not have a `value` attribute.

Finally, you're repeatedly creating new jQuery objects for `group` and `t`, which means that all previous amendments are lost. To fix this create the jQuery objects once and store them in variables which you can then reference whenever you want to make a change. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $group = $('<optgroup></optgroup>');
  $group.prop("label", "test group");

  var $t = $('<option></option>');
  $t.val(4);
  $t.prop("selected", true);
  $t.text("Test option");
  $group.append($t);
  
  $("#a").html($group);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="a"></select>
```

Note the use of `val()` to set the `value` attribute, and the use of `prop()` over `attr()` where possible.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues:

```
var group = "<optgroup></optgroup>";
$(group).attr("value", 1);
```

You are referring to the JQuery element incorrectly. What goes inside `$()` needs to be a string representing an element, a class, or an id. So if you want to change all existing optgroups, it should look like this:

```
var group = "optgroup";
$(group).attr("value", 1);
```

However, based on the rest of your code that doesn't seem to be your intention. If you are wanting to create a new optgroup, then you'll need to reference an element already in the DOM to add it to (i.e. your `#select`).

Second, your optgroup element cannot have a value, that is invalid HTML. An optgroup is a non-selectable "label" that helps break up options in a dropdown.

Third, you are creating your `<option>` element incorrectly. As mentioned before, you can't create a JQuery element with a string of an open/close for an element. You'd be better off doing something like this:

```
var t = "<option value='4' selected='selected'>Test option</option>";
$(group).append(t);
```

So your code should actually look something like this:

```
var group = "<optgroup label='test group'>";
group += "<option value='4' selected='selected'>Test option</option>";
group += "</optgroup>";
$("#select").append(group);
```

If you have at least JQuery 1.8, you can change it to this:

```js
var group = $( "<optgroup/>", { "label" : "test group"});
var option = $( "<option/>", { text : "Test option", "value" : 4, "selected" : "selected" });
group.appendTo( "#select" );
option.appendTo(group);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select"></select>
```

Comment: “What goes inside `$()` needs to be a string representing an element, a class, or an id … you can't create a jQuery element with a string of an open/close for an element.” Not true – [it is valid](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2) to pass HTML to `$()`/`jQuery()` to create DOM elements on the fly. That’s not the problematic part of OP’s code.